# Best solution for a small Discord bot and external file/db

Tags: firebase

I made a Discord bot. Its only function is if a DC member writes a keyword, the bot will send the:

- link to an image
- Link to a post

So, for each keyword, I have 2 URLs. Currently, this data is written in code. I wish to store this data in an external file or a database.

Now the problem is what is the best solution to host a bot and a file or database. I need a small free hosting service. Bot and data are very small really, so I don't need anything complex.

I thought about a few options now, although I don't know would it work:

1. to store the Discord bot at Heroku and to create a Database at the Firebase. Can the bot and db communicate this way?
2. to store both db/file and bot in Google Cloud micro instance (if it's for free). Although it sounds too complex for such a small task.
3. I've heard about the "Zapier" but I don't understand how it works, is it a good solution for my case?

In short, I need to host both a bot and a source of data, and those two should communicate. The bot should read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Zapier is not a hosting service, but a service that allows you to automate tasks between different applications.

Hosting your bot on Heroku and your database on Firebase would be a good solution for your use case. Both Heroku and Firebase offer free tiers that should be sufficient for a small bot and database (and to test it). You can use the Discord API to connect your bot to Discord and the Firebase API to connect your bot to your Firebase database. And that's it.